# Manipulating nodes in yaml-cpp

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I am currently working on a project that I would like to configure using the library [yaml-cpp](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp). Now I am trying to write a function which is given a vector of tags/strings (e.g., "A", "B", "C") and some parameter value (e.g., 31). The function should then insert a map node for each tag (if such a node does not already exist), map it to the subsequent node and finally create a scalar node with the parameter value. After the stated example call, the configuration should hence read

```
A:
  B:
    C: 31
```

Below you can see the attempt of a clean and simple implementation:

Config.hpp

```
class Config {

public:

    template<typename T>
    static void setConfigParam(const std::vector<std::string> &tags,
            T value) {
        assert(tags.size() > 0);
        assert(config);
        YAML::Node parentNode = config;
        for(int i=0; i < tags.size()-1; i++) {
            const std::string & tag = tags.at(i);
            if(parentNode[tag]) {
                YAML::Node childNode = parentNode[tag];
                parentNode = childNode;
            }
            else {
                YAML::Node childNode(YAML::NodeType::Map);
                parentNode[tag] = childNode;
                parentNode = childNode;
            }
        }
        parentNode[tags.back()] = value;
        std::cout << "Config:\n" << config << "\n\n";
    }

private:

    static YAML::Node config;

};

YAML::Node Config::config(YAML::NodeType::Map);
```

Test.cpp

```
#include "Config.hpp"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int val1 = 3;
    vector<string> tags1 = {"A1","B1","C1","D1"};
    Config::setConfigParam(tags1, val1);
    string val2 = "test";
    vector<string> tags2 = {"A1","B1","C1","D2"};
    Config::setConfigParam(tags2, val2);
    bool val3 = true;
    vector<string> tags3 = {"A1","B1","C1"};
    Config::setConfigParam(tags3, val3);
    double val4 = 2.385;
    vector<string> tags4 = {"A1","B2","C1"};
    Config::setConfigParam(tags4, val4);
}
```

The problem of the function `setConfigParam()` seem to be the lines

```
YAML::Node parentNode = config;
```

and

```
parentNode = childNode
```

According to my understanding from the [tutorial](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/wiki/Tutorial), the first line apparently creates the node `parentNode` as an alias for `config`. At each function call, the first execution of the second line then replaces the existing `config` object with the newly created `childNode`. However, in the remaining iterations the `config` is no longer being completely reset but adapted as expected.

If everything was running fine, the output should be:

```
Config:
A1:
  B1:
    C1:
      D1: 3

Config:
A1:
  B1:
    C1:
      D1: 3
      D2: test

Config:
A1:
  B1:
    C1: true

Config:
A1:
  B1:
    C1: true
  B2:
    C1: 2.385
```

The actual output of the code above is

```
Config:
B1:
  C1:
    D1: 3

Config:
B1:
  C1:
    D2: test

Config:
B1:
  C1: true

Config:
B2:
  C1: 2.385
```

I tried to prevent the mentioned issue by using pointers and finally managed to come up with the following implementation, which works correctly at least with the test code:

```
template<typename T>
static void setConfigParam(const std::vector<std::string> &tags,
        T value) {
    int numTags = tags.size();
    // Reads root node.
    assert(numTags > 0);
    assert(config);
    YAML::Node* parentNode = &config;
    // Determines index of first non-existing node.
    int i=0;
    for(; i < numTags-1; i++) {
        const std::string & tag = tags.at(i);
        if((*parentNode)[tag]) {
            auto childNode = (*parentNode)[tag];
            parentNode = &childNode;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    // Note: necessary because *parentNode will later point
    // to a different node due to lib behavior .
    YAML::Node lastExistingNode = *parentNode;
    // Sets node value and creates missing nodes.
    if(i == numTags - 1) {
        lastExistingNode[tags.back()] = value;
    }
    else {
        YAML::Node newNode;
        newNode = value;
        for(int j = tags.size()-1; j>i; j--) {
            YAML::Node tmpNode;
            tmpNode[tags.at(j)] = newNode;
            newNode = tmpNode;
        }
        // Inserts missing nodes.
        lastExistingNode[tags.at(i)] = newNode;
    }
    std::cout << "Config:\n" << config << "\n\n";
}
```

However, I believe there must be a much simpler and cleaner solution. Hence, I am very thankful for any ideas on how to get the function to work correctly with a more simple implementation, in particular as there is not too much documentation on the library.

Comment: What is the actual output of your first code snippet? You only tell us what you *expect* it to be.

Comment: My question has been answered meanwhile, but I edited it in order to add the actual output for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, assigning to an existing node has different behavior than you're intending. See [this issue](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/issues/208) for more details.

Your example with pointers gets around this problem, but it has another problem: it dereferences a stack variable.

Instead, use a recursive solution:

```
template<typename T, typename Iter>
void setConfigParam(YAML::Node node, Iter begin, Iter end, T value) {
  if (begin == end) {
    return;
  }
  const auto& tag = *begin;
  if (std::next(begin) == end) {
    node[tag] = value;
    return;
  }
  if (!node[tag]) {
    node[tag] = YAML::Node(YAML::NodeType::Map);
  }
  setConfigParam(node[tag], std::next(begin), end, value);
}
```

Comment: Your implementation works as desired, but thanks to your link I also discovered the function `reset()` for a `YAML::Node` which allows a non-recursive implementation much closer to my original attempt. Thanks also for pointing out the pointer issue.